# Ajax calls to a CORS disabled service

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, ssl, cors

Is it possible to use javascript to consume data from a webservice that is CORS disabled, only returns XML data (no option for json/jsonp) and over HTTPS? I do not have control of this webservice to make changes.

At best, if I run the following ajax I'll see an xml response getting sent back (using Chrome's developer tools) however my success function isn't being hit and I'll end up with an exception 'Unexpected syntax <' because it's anticipating a json padded response.

If I change dataType to just 'xml' I will get an error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" not found in header response. Which is what I'd except since they have not enabled CORS.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://' + myURL + querystring,
      username: usr,
      password: pwd,
      dataType:'jsonp text xml',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (data) {
          console.log( "success" );
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

You can write your own webservice that interacts with it and then access your service from JavaScript instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have mentioned that , when used `dataType` `jsonp`,i would get the response.I guess that the webservice support `jsonp`,**otherwise,the $.ajax couldn't get the response text**.And then, you mentioned:

> 'Unexpected syntax <' because it's anticipating a json padded response

The dateType of  `jsonp` in jquery will force the response text to be transformed from plain text to json object,but unfortunately the response text is returned in format of XML.

Since the webservice support `jsonp` and the jquery  require `jsonp` must be return in json format, why not use the native javascript to resolve it?

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    console.log('the return xml ',xml);
}
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxxx?param=xx&callback=parseXml"><\/script>');
```

At last,please don't reduce my marks now,its number has nearly been  down to zero for this qustion.

Comment: The question says that the service does **not** support JSONP. It returns XML not JavaScript, so you can't load it using a script element.

Comment: Also an HTML form cannot send credentials in the header, which I didn't specify but is shown in the ajax.